# AIAA default latex template does not work out the box offline

Tags: bibtex, templates, aiaa

Downloading the AIAA latex template from source will not work out the box with offline latex software. When compiling manulling using pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex, I receive the following errors in the bibtex stage (2):

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry peyret2012computational
while executing---line 1670 of file new-aiaa.bst
ptr=2, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry oates1997aerothermodynamics
while executing---line 1670 of file new-aiaa.bst

The files will compile fine on the overleaf source but don't work offline.

Source: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/latex-template-for-the-preparation-of-papers-for-aiaa-technical-conferences/rsssbwthkptn

Answer (score 1):

Update- The issues both relate to the @inbook{} entries in the sample.bib file. Changing these to @book{} types seems to fix the issue, providing the above specified build recipe is used.

Note- if you're using third party software to build the project (such as latex workshop), make sure the build recipe you are using is pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex->pdflatex.